# Will uploading my video through Vimeo package affect my server?

Tags: php, laravel, video-streaming, vimeo

I'm using https://github.com/vimeo/laravel package to upload my video to Vimeo. But there's a little problem with the file size, so I edited the php and nginx configuration to allow up to 500 request size... which isn't good (Keep in mind this is my test server and not production). I'm wondering if the package itself streams the file and uploads it or it uses as much memory as the file size and upload it at once..

Heres my code :

```
public function UploadToVimeo(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'class_id' => 'required|exists:teacher_classes,class_id',
        'video_name' => 'required|mimes:mp4,mov,ogg,qt',
    ]);
    $file = $request->video_name;
    $result = Vimeo::upload($file);
    if($result){
        $str = str_replace('/videos/','',$result);
        TeacherClass::where('class_id',$request->class_id)->update(['url'=>'https://vimeo.com'.$str]);
    }
    return back()->with('result',$str);
}
```

Can someone explain to me how the package works? Or a way to stream the file?

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking if increasing your file upload size limit will cause your server to run out of memory, or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: No. I'm asking if that package will stream the file or upload it at one time. And if its one time, will it affect my memory? or its actually from the client to vimeo server

Comment: It looks like the files are broken into chunks and sent via resumable uploads: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/blob/master/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php#L575 - you should be fine.

Comment: Oh thank you for this code. But I'm just wondering, when I request the file, does the system loads the whole file in the memory? Thats my concern. Because nginx gave me an error regarding file size and I had to edit my configuration.